# jQuery $when.apply() .. then() firing for each completed request

Tags: ajax, jquery, promise

Here's a jQuery method I've created in an ASP.NET MVC Razor view. The desired functionality is:

- Select textAreas
- Fire off an array of ajax requests
- Once all ajax requests complete, show alert dialog

The code appears to work correctly, except that the alert 'ok' dialog is displayed multiple times, once for each request. This suggests that the .then() method is being called for each request rather than waiting for all to complete. What Am I doing wrong here?

```
// Save changed entity notes
function saveChangedNotes() {

  var ajaxReqs = [];
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    ajaxReqs.push($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("UpdateCompanyNote", "Company", new {companyId = Html.CompanyIdFromRouteValues()})",
        data: {
          noteId: this.id,
          noteText: $(this).val()
        }
      })
    );

    // When all ajax complete..
    $.when.apply($, ajaxReqs).then(function() {      
      alert('ok');
    }).fail(function() {         
      alert('error');
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're performing the `$.when.apply` **inside** the textarea each loop. Count your closing brackets.

Comment: Duh.. and I thought it was me misunderstanding promises :) Thanks, good spot

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler alternative way of doing this *without using `$.when.apply` and an array at all*.

Instead use the pattern `promise = $.when(promise, anotherPromise)`.

e.g. for your example something like this

```
// Save changed entity notes
function saveChangedNotes() {
    // Start with a resolved promise (undefined does the same thing for $.when!)
    var promise;
    $('textarea').each(function () {
        promise = $.when(promise, $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("
            UpdateCompanyNote ", "
            Company ", new {companyId = Html.CompanyIdFromRouteValues()})",
            data: {
                noteId: this.id,
                noteText: $(this).val()
            }
        }));
    });
    // When all ajax complete..
    promise.then(function () {
        alert('ok');
    }).fail(function () {
        alert('error');
    });
}
```

Comment: I intuitively did that as well - using arrays and coding with side effects seems to be unnatural with functional-style jquery apporach. But I think it should be just `promise`, not `$promise` in the last statement. Just a typo.

Comment: @Alex Pakka: Thanks. Yes that was a cut/paste typo. Cheers